# I have select query issue

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have 2 tables in my db. In first table I have GroupName and LID columns,in second table I have strSO,strLID and DefectDes columns. LID and strLID columns has same values. Every GroupName has DefectDes like `See Disposition Table` and `Not Disassembled`. For example, some groups has one `See Disposition Table` and one `Not Disassembled`; some groups has no `See Disposition Table`. I want to take group names like this **some groups has no `See Disposition Table`. I wrote this code for do it

```
deneme=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM TableRun WHERE LID IN (SELECT strLID FROM TableResult  WHERE strSO='"+SalesOrder+"' AND DefectDes='Not Disassembled')");
         while(deneme.next())
         {
             System.out.println(deneme.getString("GroupName"));
         }
```

But it gives me wrong answer.

My db tables are like this
[image]

[image]

The answer like this

```
STG 1 HPT VANE
STG 11 HPC VANE
STG 2 HPT VANE
STG 3 HPC VARIABLE VANE
STG 4 HPC BLADE
STG 4 HPC VARIABLE VANE
STG 5 HPC BLADE
STG 6 HPC BLADE
STG 7 HPC VANE
STG 8 HPC VANE
STG 9 HPC BLADE
STG 9 HPC VANE
```

In the answer **STG 1 HPT VANE** ,has one record `See Disposition Table` and one record `Not disassembled`. I don't want to get it. I just want to get all the `Not Disassembled` LIDs.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's still gives me same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupName FROM TableResult left join TableRun on TableResult.strLID = TableRun.LID WHERE strSO='"+SalesOrder+"' AND DefectDes='Not Disassembled' group by GroupName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join instead of inline query also I can not find **STG 1 HPT VANE** in your data table. I don't know what is the **LID** of **STG 1 HPT VANE** but hope this query will help you

```
deneme=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT TRun.GroupName FROM TableRun TRun
inner join tableresult TResult on Trun.LID = TResult.strLID
WHERE TResult.strSO='"+SalesOrder+"' AND TResult.DefectDes='Not Disassembled' group by TRun.GroupName" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will concatenate all the DefectDes values and filter using `HAVING` claue

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.GroupName
FROM TableRun r  
WHERE r.LID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT rs.strLID FROM TableResult rs 
WHERE r.LID = rs.strLID AND rs.strSO='"+SalesOrder+"'
GROUP BY rs.strLID
HAVING group_concat(rs.DefectDes) LIKE '%Not Disassembled%'
AND group_concat(rs.DefectDes) NOT LIKE '%See Disposition Table%')
```

Comment: It gives me this error. -> `UCAExc:::3.0.7 user lacks privilege or object not found: DEFDES`

Comment: `select o.orderId, group_concat(productId) as defdes
from Orders o join orderDetails d on o.orderId = d.orderId
group by o.orderId
HAVING defdes LIKE '%11%'
AND defdes NOT LIKE '%42%'` at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in works. It basically returns orders with product 11 but not 42.. which database are you using?

Comment: Yeah,its running in **w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in** but I don't understand why its not running from me.

Comment: `UCAExc:::3.0.7 expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: R.GROUPNAME` . Gives me this error now :)

Comment: try now :P Please green tick the answer if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198880/discussion-between-kishita-and-mustafa-berkan-demir).